# Mass email message apex

Tags: email-template, massemailmessage

I need to send mass email message through apex. I cannot able to set the body, orgwideaddressId.. How can we convert a single message to mass message?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [MassEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) class available for sending mass email. You can write something like this. Please note this code is for reference only. This [developer forum link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093HNIAY) may be of your help.

```
Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]);

EmailTemplate template =  [SELECT Id, Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Unique_API_Name' LIMIT 1];

Messaging.MassEmailMessage emails=new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
emails.setTargetObjectIds(contactMap.keySet());
emails.setTemplateId(template.Id);
emails.setsubject('note');
Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[]{emails});
```